# Dirty Checking in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was recently going through a pretty interesting article about [data binding in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs?rq=1).
I came across a term there : 'Dirty-Checking', which is performed during a `$digest` operation. The term sounded quite interesting to me but unfortunately, didn't make much sense about what's dirty over there. Does it concern the constant check on some value ?

Answer (score 0):

The term `dirty checking` refers to the process of comparing values from before a change (`$digest` cycle) and after a change.

[This blog](http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/#dirty-checking) does a pretty good job explaining the details.

So, when the digest cycle runs in Angular, all the *watched* scope values (bound to the ui, or using `$watch`) are traversed.  Each value is resolved and then compared to the value in a previous digest.  So, it is checking if the values have been changed (whether they are *dirty*).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Davin.

I went through the blog link you provided. Sorry to say but I think it's meaning is bit different from the last line you mentioned.

The term dirty-check is probably named so because there is 'watch' associated with every'$scope value' instead checking if the values have been changed (whether they are dirty).

Just trying to clear my concepts. :)